# MEF import object in child class is NULL

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm facing a strange issue where an object can be imported just fine in a class.
If I create an instance of another class from the first class, then try to import the same object in the child class, the import always fails!

First class:

```
public class Foo {

    [Import]
    private SomeExportedType foobar;

    public Foo() {
        foobar.Test(); // Works just fine

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.Test();
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class Bar {

    [Import]
    private SomeExportedType foobar;

    public void Test() {
        foobar.Test(); // This fails because foobar is NULL
    }
}
```

All of this is pseudo code, or course, but it correctly reflects how my code is built.
Why does the import in the child class fail?

Comment: How is the "Foo" class instantiated? Imports are not satisfied if you simply new up a class using it's constructor... part of the reason I hate property injection actually... does not accurately declare it's dependencies.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment on your answer, "Foo" is instantiated by MEF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By newing up your Bar class manually you are bypassing MEF and therefore the imports are not being satisfied, you should allow MEF to be in charge of newing up classes.

```
public class Foo {

    [Import]
    private SomeExportedType foobar;

    [Import]
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo() {
        foobar.Test(); // Works just 

        bar.Test(); // Should also work fine.
    }
}
```

Try importing an instance of your Bar class as well.. that way it will be instantiated by MEF and the imports satisfied.

Comment: This was it. I had seen comments about this previously, but I thought that as long as Foo was instantiated by MEF, then Bar would also keep the MEF connection even when being instantiated by Foo. Apparently not, though. I changed the implementation so that Bar exports itself and Foo imports it, then it worked like a charm.

Comment: @GTHvidsten This is one of the problems I have with "Property Injection", I feel it hides dependencies that the class requires. I tend to use the "ImportingConstructor" attribute instead which allows me to new up the class manually should I need to.